# Journalling stdout with systemd when running as specific user

Tags: systemd, journald

Consider the following `test-echo.service`:

```
[Unit]
Description=Testing journalling of stdout

[Service]
ExecStart=/bin/echo hello world

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

Its stdout ends up in the journal as expected:

```
$ sudo systemctl enable test-echo
$ sudo systemctl start test-echo
$ sudo journalctl -e -u test-echo
> ... systemd[1]: Started Testing journalling of stdout.
> ... echo[20178]: hello world
$ sudo systemctl stop test-echo
```

Now I add `User=ubuntu` under the `[Service]` section. `ubuntu` is an existing regular user.

```
$ sudo systemctl daemon-reload
$ sudo systemctl start test-echo
$ sudo journalctl -e -u test-echo
> ... systemd[1]: Started Testing journalling of stdout.
```

Note that the echo message is now missing from the journal. Why is this, and how can I get it to show up?

I am using systemd 229 on Ubuntu 16.04.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`journald` is currently unable to attribute the output of processes shortly before they exit, which is especially the case for very short lived processes like `echo`.
This is caused due to how `journald` acquires certain information (e.g. the `_SYSTEMD_UNIT` and `_COMM` fields) from the process' `/proc`, which might not exist anymore at the point your output is processed.

You can find the bug report [on GitHub](https://github.com/systemd/systemd/issues/2913) as well as [on the Bugzilla](https://bugs.freedesktop.org/show_bug.cgi?id=50184).

Comment: So a `sleep 1` right after the `echo` would band-aid this?

Comment: @chicks In my experience and as far as I understand it: Yes. You can see it in the GitHub issue description how he added a (quite short) `sleep 0.1` after the first `echo before sleep`, which was enough to allow him to see it in the logs.